# Using induction to prove bubble sort is correct

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

How can we show, using induction, that bubble sort is correct?  How do we choose the invariant to follow throughout the formulation of the proof (this step seems like an arbitrary task to me, so if it can be explained more deeply I would greatly appreciate it)?

I understand that the largest elements will always end up at the end of the list after each iteration, but I don't know how to use this fact to show that the algorithm is correct.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably this would be a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but his is how I see it.

The idea behind bubble sort is that you go though the vector of values (left to right). I am calling this a pass. During the pass pairs of values are checked and swapped to be in correct order (higher right).

During first pass the maximum value will be reached. When reached the max will be higher then value next to it, so they will be swapped. This means that max will become part of next pair in the pass. This repeats until pass is completed and max is left at the right end of the vector.

During second pass the same is true for the second highest value in the vector. Only difference is it will not be swapped with the max at the end. Now two most right values are correctly set.

I every next pass one value will be sorted out to the right.

There are N values and N passes. This means that after N passes all N values will be sorted